# Linux x-terminal switch terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

Run this command from console 1

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "path to executable script"
```

After this command, how do I come back to the first console 1?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Run the command in the background with `&` at the end.

Comment: question unclear. Does the terminal window has to remain open and is the script done or be running?

Comment: The second terminal and first terminal both has to remain open. The script should be running in second running terminal. Now how would I come back to first terminal

Answer (score 0):

To run a command in the background, append `&` to the end like so:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "path to executable script" &
```

Alternatively, you can run the command and then press `CTRL+Z` to put it in the background, and if you want it to continue running in the background once you close console-1, you can do `disown` like so:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e "path to executable script" &
<PRESS CTRL+Z>
disown
```

Hope this helps!